# value_type for a map having pointers as key

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

For what I know, C++ defines `map<a,b>::value_type` as `pair<const a,b>`

What will happen if I use a pointer type as key type in map, i.e., is

```
std::map<const char*,int>::value_type::first_type = const char*
```

as I would expect from definition above or

```
std::map<const char*,int>::value_type::first_type = const char* const
```

as would be more logical (since otherwise i would be allowed to change key value from a map iterator)?

Comment: consider using std::string instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct, `value_type::first` would be `char const * const`.

There is a common source of confusion in thinking that `const T` when `T` is a `type *` is `const type *`, but that is not so. Unlike macros, `typedef`s are not text substitution, nor are template arguments. When you do `const T`, if `T` is a `typedef` or template argument, you are adding a `const` to the type as a whole.

That is the one reason why I like to write my `const`s at the right of the type, as it causes less confusion: `T const *`, add an extra const, get `T const * const`.

Comment: that's relieving. I guess we should diffuse, expecially among new programmers, the convention of using `type const` instead of `const type`, which would avoid confusions in the case where `type` is a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

If `a` is `const char*`, then `const a` is indeed `const char* const`.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in your assessment, but you have to be very careful with this approach for two reasons:

1. You have to supply a custom comparator predicate that does proper ordering of const char * (e.g., using a variant of strcmp that only returns true if key1 < key2 ). If you do not do this, your strings will be ordered by pointer values, which is almost always not what you want.
2. You have to consider the lifetime of the keys in your map and how they will be deallocated when the map is destroyed.

Comment: yes, usually that would be a common mistake, however there are cases in which you really just want to compare pointers instead of strings (examples: if you have compile time constant strings as key, like a printable version of an enum, or if you're making a map from HWND to relative window handling object in a winapi event management)